# Get the last part of the value returned by split_part() function

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

I have a file_path string separated by forward slashes. I want to split them based on the forward slashes and return the file name.

**INPUT**

```
//a/b/c/xyz.png
```

**OUTPUT**

```
xyz.png
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION**

```
SELECT REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE('//a/b/c/xyz.py'), '/', 1)) as "file_name";
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regexp_match()` is more concise:

```
select (regexp_match('//a/b/c/xyz.py', '[^/]+$'))[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL 14 will support negative index so it will be straightforward operation.

> **[split_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-string.html)**
>
> Splits string at occurrences of delimiter and returns the n'th field (counting from one), or **when n is negative, returns the |n|'th-from-last field.**
>
> ```
> split_part('abc,def,ghi,jkl', ',', -2) → ghi
> ```

In this particular scenario:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('//a/b/c/xyz.py', '/', -1) as "file_name";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `regexp_replace()` to remove everything before the last slash (included):

```
select regexp_replace('//a/b/c/xyz.png', '.*/', '')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8fd1be6e4bcd502a882872556fc233f*)**:

```
| regexp_replace |
| :------------- |
| xyz.png        |
```

You can also use `substring()`, which may or may not be more efficient:

```
substring('//a/b/c/xyz.png' from '[^/]*$')
```